# Generic DAO and nested properties support

Tags: java, hibernate, genericdao, hibernate-generic-dao

I am trying to perform a DB access through a DAO object, and I have bumped into the case where I need to query a field in another Entity.

Considering two entities (EntityA and EntityB) that are connected in entity A through the foreign key `EntityA.idEntityB`.

I have `GenericDao<EntityA> daoA` and I am trying to get all the results that match a determined field of EntityB: `idEntityB.fieldOfB` all in the same *find* method of the dao.

Is it possible? And if so some directions would be nice. Thanks

**edit**

An example of my code:

#### Entities

```
public class EntityA {
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_entity_b", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private EntityB idEntityB;
    // getter+setter...
}

public class EntityB {
    // ...
    private String fieldOfB;
    // getter+setter...
}
```

#### DAO Access

```
GenericDao<EntityA> daoA = // ...

Set<Criterion> filter = new HashSet<Criterion>();
filter.add(Restrictions.eq("idEntityB.fieldOfB"));

List<EntityA> list = dao.findByFilter(filter);
```

The error message is something like "*Could not resolve property idEntityB.fieldOfB*"

**edit 2**

I was able to find something like what I want to do. Although my API is slightly different I believe this is helful for anyone who gets across this problem at an early stage of their own project.

http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/

> The framework features a powerful and flexible search functionality.
>   This is used by passing a search object to search methods on general
>   and generic DAOs.

Searches with nested properties are fully supported in this project.

Comment: Could you post your current code?

Comment: Why not just load EntytyB via it's ID which is in EntytyA?

Comment: Is the result of your query a collection of type EntityA?

Comment: @JamesB - Yes, the final result would ideally be a List<EntityA>

Comment: @RomanC - I had that initiall, but my goal is to enable **searches** by any field in EntityB

Comment: @PetrPudlák - I have edited the question with an example of my current code. I guess the important line is `filter.add(Restrictions.eq("idEntityB.fieldOfB"));`

Comment: If idEntityB is simply an identifier (say, a Long) then there is no way that idEntityB.fieldOfB is going to be resolved. You need to make entity B a composite type of entity A in order to access the fields of B.

Comment: I wrote myself a generic DAO which also allows simple filtering on nested subproperties via reflection and Criteria API with dynamic fetching if necessary regarding the filters. When I am back at home I can post some of my code. I first create a tree structure from the filtering property strings like `foo.bar.name` and then add restrictions on a criteria from that tree.

Comment: @djmj - That seems cool, and your code is very welcome. However, I thought there was a way to enable nested fetching with annotations (or xml configurations). Something like `@OneToMany(...fetch = FetchType.EAGER...)` on the property I want to use.

Comment: @nuno Yes you are right. I don't have the code in front of me. But as a tradeoff I always use eager fetching in xml for one to many properties (not for collections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my generic Criteria filtering method.

Properties according to bean conventions have following form `foo.bar.name`.
With Criteria API a tree can be build from a given filtering map and Restrictions can be added. One special case I observed during testing is that filtering on the identifier property does not needs a new subcriteria since this property is already fetched.

```
/**
 * Creates a detached criteria from the given Type and given map of filters.
 * 
 * @param type Target type the Criteria is build for.
 * @param identifierPropertyName If provided (not null) the identifier
 *            property name can be identified for the given type to simplify
 *            the queries if the identifier property is the only property
 *            used on the parent no subqueries are needed.
 * @param filters
 * 
 * @see #createTree(Set, String)
 * @see #addRestrictions(DetachedCriteria, TreeNode)
 * 
 * @return
 */
public static DetachedCriteria createDetachedCriteria(final Class<?> type, final String identifierPropertyName,
    final Map<String, Criterion> filters)
{
    final DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(type);

    // add restrictions using tree
    final TreeNode<Entry<String, Criterion>> rootNode = HibernateUtils2.createTree(filters.entrySet(),
        identifierPropertyName);

    final Iterator<TreeNode<Entry<String, Criterion>>> it = rootNode.getChildren().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
        HibernateUtils.addRestrictions(criteria, it.next());

    return criteria;
}

/**
 * Creates a Tree from the given Set using a fictional root TreeNode.
 * 
 * @param <T>
 * 
 * @param filters
 * @param identifierPropertyName Property name which is merged with its
 *            parent property. Example: <b>user.id</b> is treated as single
 *            property.
 * @return
 */
public static <T extends Object> TreeNode<Entry<String, T>> createTree(final Set<Entry<String, T>> filters,
    final String identifierPropertyName)
{

    final Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> it = filters.iterator();

    /*
     * create key property tree for Entity properties
     */
    final TreeNode<Entry<String, Object>> rootNode = new TreeNode<Entry<String, Object>>(
        new SimpleEntry<String, Object>("root", null));

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        final Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
        // foo.bar.name
        final String key = entry.getKey();

        String[] props;

        /*
         * check if we have a nested hierarchy
         */
        if (key.contains("."))
        {
            props = key.split("\\.");
            // check for identifier since identifier property name does not
            // need new subcriteria
            if (!StringUtils.isBlank(identifierPropertyName))
            {
                int propsTempLength = props.length - 1;
                if (props[propsTempLength].equals(identifierPropertyName))
                {
                    props = Arrays.copyOf(props, propsTempLength);
                    propsTempLength--;
                    props[propsTempLength] = props[propsTempLength] + "." + identifierPropertyName;
                }
            }

            // check for "this" identifier of beginning, which needs to be
            // added for projections because of hibernate not recognizing it
            if (props.length > 1 && props[0].equals("this"))
            {
                props[0] = "this." + props[1];

                props = ArrayUtils.remove(props, 1);
            }
        }
        else
            props = new String[]
            {
                key
            };

        TreeNode<Entry<String, Object>> currNode = rootNode;

        // create nested criteria
        for (int i = 0; i < props.length; i++)
        {
            Object valueAdd;

            // only leaf needs value
            if (i != props.length - 1)
                valueAdd = null;
            else
                valueAdd = entry.getValue();

            final TreeNode<Entry<String, Object>> childTempNode = new TreeNode<Entry<String, Object>>(
                new SimpleEntry<String, Object>(props[i], valueAdd));

            // try to get the real node
            TreeNode<Entry<String, Object>> childNode = currNode.getChild(childTempNode.getElement());
            // check if we already have a unique node
            if (childNode == null)
            {
                childNode = childTempNode;
                // add new child to set if its a new node
                currNode.addChild(childNode);
            }

            currNode = childNode;
        }
    }

    return rootNode;
}

/**
 * Recursively adds the given Restriction's wrapped in the given TreeNode to
 * the Criteria.
 * 
 * @param criteria
 * @param treeNode
 */
public static void addRestrictions(final DetachedCriteria criteria,
    final TreeNode<Entry<String, Criterion>> treeNode)
{
    // if we have a leaf simply add restriction
    if (treeNode.getChildren().size() == 0)
        criteria.add(treeNode.getElement().getValue());
    else
    {
        // create new sub Criteria and iterate children's
        final DetachedCriteria subCriteria = criteria.createCriteria(treeNode.getElement().getKey());

        final Iterator<TreeNode<Entry<String, Criterion>>> it = treeNode.getChildren().iterator();

        while (it.hasNext())
            HibernateUtils.addRestrictions(subCriteria, it.next());
    }
}

/*
 * Utility classes
 */

/**
 * Generic TreeNode implementation with a Set to hold its children to only allow
 * unique children's.
 */
public class TreeNode<T>
{
    private final T element;

    private final Set<TreeNode<T>> childrens;

    public TreeNode(final T element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element cannot be null");

        this.element = element;

        this.childrens = new HashSet<TreeNode<T>>();
    }

    public void addChildren(final TreeNode<T> children)
    {
        this.childrens.add(children);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the children which equals the given one.
     * 
     * @param children
     * @return If no children equals the given one returns null.
     */
    public TreeNode<T> getChildren(final TreeNode<T> children)
    {
        final Iterator<TreeNode<T>> it = this.childrens.iterator();

        TreeNode<T> next = null;

        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            next = it.next();
            if (next.equals(children))
                return next;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public T getElement()
    {
        return this.element;
    }

    public Set<TreeNode<T>> getChildrens()
    {
        return this.childrens;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the element of this instance equals the one of the given
     * Object.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;

        if (obj != null && obj instanceof TreeNode)
        {
            final TreeNode<?> treeNode = (TreeNode<?>) obj;

            return this.element.equals(treeNode.element);
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 1;
        hash = hash * 17 + this.element.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Or have a look at the generic dao project you mentioned. I knew about this project and checked it out but never downloaded it.

Using this approach a query can be created very simple like following:

```
Map<String, Object> filters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
filters.put("foo.bar.name", Restrictions.like("name", "peter"));
filters.put("foo.test.id", Restrictions.eq("id", 2));

List<Class> data = HibernateUtils.createDetachedCriteria(Class, "get identifier from sessionFactory", filters).getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
```

*This odd approach to add the property name as the key and into the Restrictions is related to the fact that Restrictions have no getter and setter for property names.*

**Custom filtering**

My real application uses similar code which is not restricted to `Criterion` class only.
For my web tier I created custom filters which are equivalent to Restrictions api but the client does not needs hibernate jar's anymore.

**Edit**

Generic filtering across non-entities such as component's and composite-id's is not supported. It can easily be extended with help of `ClassMetadata` to support them without need for reflection. If code is needed i can provide it.

Comment: Thank you. My project must support other kinds of operators so I will try to add to you code operator tokens and a generic criteria building mechanism like `Utils.buildCriteria(String prop, OPERATOR op, Object value);`, where `equals` applied in FK and the `op` operator is applied on tha last nested property. This was indeed very helpful. Answer accepted and +1.

Comment: I am having trouble finging a compatible implementation of the TreeNode you are using. Could you post the code for it aswell when you can?

Comment: Added the TreeNode implementation and fixed the identifier property problem.

Comment: @nuno In your question you did not mentioned the use of custom filters. Currently i am using custom filters on my client (client does not need hibernate jar's) And the criteria build method can take any kind of Object (Criterion, Custom-Filter, Object) and adds restrictions depending on the type of value. If you are interested in that approach I can provide you some code. I just removed any unrelated code just to support Criterion's in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this example: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/

You need to declare the relationships between the entities as

```
public class EntityA {
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_entity_b")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private EntityB idEntityB;
    // getter+setter... and the rest
}
```

Instead of `Integer` use `EntityB`.

That's the point of [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_relational_mapping) that Hibernate provides: You don't need to work with keys, you work with objects. Converting this representation into the relational mapping with keys is the work of Hibernate's ORM layer.

Comment: Yes, actually my code is using it this way. Sorry, I transcripted it wrong from my code. (code in original question is now similar to my code)